# Is it Possible to save results from a CASE Query in a Table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to make a case query and save it also into the table in the same query?

```
DECLARE @DateVal_1 DATE = '2022-07-01';

SELECT *,
CASE
    WHEN FORMAT(@DateVal_1,'dddd') = 'Montag' THEN Mo_AnzahlMitarbeiter
    WHEN FORMAT(@DateVal_1,'dddd') = 'Dienstag' THEN Di_AnzahlMitarbeiter
    WHEN FORMAT(@DateVal_1,'dddd') = 'Mittwoch' THEN Mi_AnzahlMitarbeiter
    WHEN FORMAT(@DateVal_1,'dddd') = 'Donnerstag' THEN Do_AnzahlMitarbeiter
    WHEN FORMAT(@DateVal_1,'dddd') = 'Freitag' THEN Fr_AnzahlMitarbeiter
    WHEN FORMAT(@DateVal_1,'dddd') = 'Samstag' THEN Sa_AnzahlMitarbeiter
    WHEN FORMAT(@DateVal_1,'dddd') = 'Sonntag' THEN So_AnzahlMitarbeiter
END AS Tag1_Anzahl_Ist,
FROM Table1
```

thanks for help!

Comment: You want to SAVE results of the query in an existing table or ... ? Also please tag your database. Is it SQLServer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use

> INSERT INTO

```
DECLARE @DateVal_1 DATE = '2022-07-01';

INSERT INTO your_table (field_name)
SELECT *,
CASE
    WHEN FORMAT(@DateVal_1,'dddd') = 'Montag' THEN Mo_AnzahlMitarbeiter
    WHEN FORMAT(@DateVal_1,'dddd') = 'Dienstag' THEN Di_AnzahlMitarbeiter
    WHEN FORMAT(@DateVal_1,'dddd') = 'Mittwoch' THEN Mi_AnzahlMitarbeiter
    WHEN FORMAT(@DateVal_1,'dddd') = 'Donnerstag' THEN Do_AnzahlMitarbeiter
    WHEN FORMAT(@DateVal_1,'dddd') = 'Freitag' THEN Fr_AnzahlMitarbeiter
    WHEN FORMAT(@DateVal_1,'dddd') = 'Samstag' THEN Sa_AnzahlMitarbeiter
    WHEN FORMAT(@DateVal_1,'dddd') = 'Sonntag' THEN So_AnzahlMitarbeiter
END AS Tag1_Anzahl_Ist,
FROM Table1
```